# How to check if an input is a multiple of a number?

Tags: python, modulus

I have an if/else statement in my program, and the if statement checks 3 factors, one being if the input given from the user is a multiple of 5, and if it is not, it runs the program. I am currently using the modulus operator, but even when I input a multiple of 5 it still runs the program instead of moving on to the else statement.

Here is my code:

```py
 if(cost == 0) or (cost > 100) or (cost != 100%5):
```

Comment: Where does 100 come from in the last condition?

Comment: Multiple of 5 is `cost%5 == 0`

Comment: The problem is your 100%5 which is always 0. So it states if(cost != 0) which is always true except cost is 0. due to the initial (cost ==0) you even take this condition. So your condition is useless.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a number is a multiple of x, use the following code:

```
number % x == 0
```

To check if this is not the case, simply replace the "==" with "!=":

```
number % x != 0
```

For more information regarding the modulo operation visit the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)